# I am getting error while executing below query in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SP_ADDTYPE 'SWORKSTATIONID_TYPE_TEMP', 'VARCHAR(256)', NULL
```

Comment: This is syntactically valid, you need to *show the error* you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

First, to run a stored procedure, use `exec`:

```
EXEC SP_ADDTYPE 'SWORKSTATIONID_TYPE_TEMP', 'VARCHAR(256)', NULL ;
```

Second, this is deprecated.  Use `CREATE TYPE` instead (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql)).